# Order of a map $\Bbb F_{p^n}\to \Bbb F_{p^n}$which maps $x$ to $x^{p} -x$

Tags: finite-fields, group-homomorphism

Let $\Bbb F_{p^{n}}$ be the field of order $p^{n}$.
Define a map $\phi: \Bbb F_{p^{n}}\to\Bbb F_{p^{n}}$ by $x \mapsto x^{p} -x$.
My question is what is the order of im$(\phi)$?

I already know Frobenius automorphism $\sigma: \Bbb F_{p^{n}}\to\Bbb F_{p^{n}}$ via $x \mapsto x^{p}$ has order $n$. But it seems that any work with $\sigma$ does not involve $\phi$.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: The kernel of $\phi$  is the subfield $\Bbb{F}_p$, and its image consists of the elements of trace zero.

Comment: My question is answered at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1384817/proof-check-number-of-elements-of-mathbbf-pn-of-the-form-ap-a-fo?rq=1. Plz close this post as it duplicated.